# Unpivot dynamic table columns into key value rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-migration, unpivot, cross-apply

The problem that I need to resolve is data transfer from one table with many dynamic fields into other structured key value table. 
The first table comes from a data export from another system, and has the following structure ( it can have any column name and data):
[UserID],[FirstName],[LastName],[Email],[How was your day],[Would you like to receive weekly newsletter],[Confirm that you are 18+] ...

The second table is where I want to put the data, and it has the following structure:
[UserID uniqueidentifier],[QuestionText nvarchar(500)],[Question Answer nvarchar(max)]

I saw many examples showing how to unpivot table, but my problem is that I dont know what columns the Table 1 will have. Can I somehow dynamically unpivot the first table,so no matter what columns it has, it is converted into a key-value structure and import the data into the second table.

I will really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Kindly post some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pivot or unpivot in one query without knowing the columns.

What you can do, assuming you have privileges, is query `sys.columns` to get the field names of your source table then build an unpivot query dynamically.

```
--Source table
create table MyTable (
    id int,
    Field1 nvarchar(10),
    Field2 nvarchar(10),
    Field3 nvarchar(10)
);

insert into MyTable (id, Field1, Field2, Field3) values ( 1, 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' );
insert into MyTable (id, Field1, Field2, Field3) values ( 2, 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg' );
insert into MyTable (id, Field1, Field2, Field3) values ( 3, 'hhh', 'iii', 'jjj' );

--key/value table
create table MyValuesTable (
    id int,
    [field] sysname,
    [value] nvarchar(10)
);



declare @columnString nvarchar(max)

--This recursive CTE examines the source table's columns excluding
--the 'id' column explicitly and builds a string of column names
--like so: '[Field1], [Field2], [Field3]'.

;with columnNames as (
  select column_id, name
  from sys.columns 
  where object_id = object_id('MyTable','U')
    and name <> 'id'
),
columnString (id, string) as (
  select
    2, cast('' as nvarchar(max))
  union all
  select
    b.id + 1, b.string + case when b.string = '' then '' else ', ' end + '[' + a.name + ']'
  from
    columnNames a
    join columnString b on b.id = a.column_id
)
select top 1 @columnString = string from columnString order by id desc

--Now I build a query around the column names which unpivots the source and inserts into the key/value table.
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = '
insert MyValuestable
select id, field, value
from
  (select * from MyTable) b
unpivot
  (value for field in (' + @columnString + ')) as unpvt'

--Query's ready to run.
exec (@sql)

select * from MyValuesTable
```

In case you're getting your source data from a stored procedure, you can use `OPENROWSET` to get the data into a table, then examine that table's column names. This link shows how to do that part.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228165/300242

Final note: If you use a temporary table, remember that you get the column names from `tempdb.sys.columns` like so:

```
select column_id, name
from tempdb.sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#MyTable','U')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @JC. This worked quite well for me. I really appreciate your help.